# Remove 'Reshuffle' button in GANTT- FSL

Tags: apex, custom-button, field-service-lightning, fsl

I want to remove reshuffle, Schedule buttons from GANTT display:

[image]

I can't find any option sin field service admin settings.

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 3):

The visibility of these buttons is controlled by custom permissions assigned to the user via profile or permission set. Refer to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pfs_custom_permissions.htm&type=5)

> Reshuffle - Reshuffle appointments from the appointment action menu or
> when you right-click services on the Gantt.
>
> Schedule - Schedule an appointment from the appointment list or from the
> map.

API names of custom permissions responsible for these action:

- `FSL__Reshuffle`;
- `FSL__Schedule`.